# Set Mindate to a decade back in bootstrap datepicker

Tags: jquery

I would like to set the min date of bootstrap date picker a decade back. Any suggestions?

```
mindate = new Date().getFullYear() - 10
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason you need to add `startDate` to the options. Check here: http://jsfiddle.net/LcqM7/373/

```
$('#sandbox-container input').datepicker({
    startDate: "today",
    minDate:'-1d',
});
```

to get minDate 10 years ago use what @Jayesh suggested:

```
    minDate:'-10Y',
```

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
 $('.date').datepicker({
    dateFormat:'yy-mm-dd',
    minDate:'-10Y', //set min date 10 years back like this
  });
```